# unable to open iOS 10 simualtor via Appium using xCode 8 beta

Tags: java, ios-simulator, appium, appium-ios, xcode8-beta2

i am trying to open iOS 10 simulator using appium 1.4.14 using the XCode 8 beta.

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "10.0"); 
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPad Air");

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "8.0");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM,"Mac");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,     "iPad Air");
    capabilities.setCapability("sendKeyStrategy","setValue");
    capabilities.setCapability("--no-reset", false);
```

My appium server code is like this

```
 CommandLine command = new CommandLine("/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node");
    command.addArgument("/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js", false);
    command.addArgument("--address", false);
    command.addArgument("127.0.0.1");
    command.addArgument("--port", false);
    command.addArgument("4723");
    //command.addArgument("--no-reset", false);
    command.addArgument("--full-reset", true);
    command.addArgument("--session-override", true);
```

I am getting the following error --- Could not find a device to launch. You requested 'iPhone (10.0 Simulator)', but the available devices were: ["iPad Air (10.0) [762BD271-B724-46DA-8312-4231A1BC4AD3] (Simulator)"]

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the **Xcode default path to the Beta version**.

Check the current path using 
    **xcode-select --print-path**

Update the xcode beta location path using 
    **sudo xcode-select --switch**

Answer (score 0):

```
[caps]
platformName = "iOS"
orientation = "PORTRAIT"
platformVersion = "9.3"
deviceName ="iPhone Simulator"
noReset = "true"
automationName = "xcuitest"
appiumVersion = "1.6.0-beta1"
app="/<pathtoapp>/<appname>.app"
[appium_lib]
```

- Use automation name as xcuitest and specify appium version to be used
- Check list of devices - xcrun simctl list and use below capabilities

Answer (score -1):

I have successfully launched iphone simulator with the following code in eclipse with appium server using ios10 update with Xcode8 using XCUITest.

please see the code in img attached.

[image]

Comment: You can install it with npm install -g appium@beta, and get the new system by setting the automationName desired capability to XCUITest.